# How to implement a scene graph to WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have some trouble organizing the various matrix-multiplications to implement a scene graph to my WebGL-scene.

Until now, I used to have three matrices, the *projectionMatrix*, the *viewMatrix* and the *modelMatrix* (the *normalMatrix* aside), which are multiplicated in that same order. I also have a *node*-object, which holds basically all information needed to draw something.

While the *projectionMatrix* and the *viewMatrix* are updated separately by a `drawScene`-function, the *modelMatrix* is equal to each nodes *localMatrix*, which - with every drawing-call - is set to *identity* and then transformed the way I want.

The nodes are stored in an array (`nodeList`) and when the `drawScene`-function is called, I loop through this list and tell each node to draw itself.

Now I've read the tutorial for implementing a scene graph to WebGL on [www.webglfundamentals.org](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-scene-graph.html) and tried to add this feature to my *scene*-function, but though this tutorial is very well written, I am still a bit confused of how to get this done.

Following this tutorial, each *node* has to have not just a *localMatrix*, but also a *worldMatrix*. Then, if a node is the *root*-element (i.e. when it has no parent-node), their *localMatrix* and their *worldMatrix* are identical, otherwise, if there *is* a parent-node, the *worldMatrix* of the child-node is computed by multiplying their *localMatrix* with the *worldMatrix* of their parent-node, so that the *worldMatrix* of each node is what in my former code used to be the *modelMatrix* / *localMatrix*.

Maybe I just can't see the forest for the trees, but I ask myself when and where to call the function to *update* the world-matrices of the nodes and when to set the matrices back to *identity*, once for all, just for the root-node or for each node separately?

I mean, the code provided in said tutorial does it by traversing recursively through all children of a node, but my `nodeList`-array doesn't reflect the potential hierarchical relations of the nodes and with every drawing-call, the local-matrices are set back to *identity*. So, it cannot work this way, can it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Sorry my previous answer was about something else and it is not implemented this way in tutorial (sadly).

> which - with every drawing-call - is set to identity and then transformed the way I want.

Why do you set anything back to identity? You shouldnt do that.

> but my `nodeList`-array doesn't reflect the potential hierarchical relations of the nodes and with every drawing-call, the local-matrices are set back to identity. So, it cannot work this way, can it?

Purpose of scene graph is to simplify and avoid additional mathematical operations. This require nodes in tree hierarchy.

**Initialization**

Lest have nodes from tutorial:

```
var node = {
   localMatrix: ...,  // the "local" matrix for this node
   worldMatrix: ...,  // the "world" matrix for this node
   children: [],      // array of children
   thingToDraw: ??,   // thing to draw at this node
};
```

Then you have two things, root node of entire scene and `nodeList` where important nodes are (these that might be transformed in future).

```
var rootNode = new Node();
var nodeList = [];
```

Now put all the stuff in node hierarchy, all the nodes are part of rootNode. And these that might transform in the future save in nodeList.

**Stages are repeat for each `tick()`**

**Stage 1 - update**

Update location of all elements that you want, which means pick stuff from nodeList and transform `localMatrix`. You doesnt do anything with parent or children.

**Stage 2 - find world position**

When all the updates are done, you need to recalculate all worldMatrices. Which means destroy old `worldMatrix` and create new one. You do this with `rootNode.updateWorldMatrix()`. This will go from top to bottom and calculate new `worldMatrix` for each node in the tree based on parent worldMatrix and node localMatrix. It does not change `localMatrix`.

**Stage 3 - drawcall**

Now we are back to old known projection, view and model matrix. Do something like `rootNode.draw()`, which is recursive function that will draw each node in hierarchy. Model matrix = `worldMatrix`.

**About**

As you see there is no setIdentity in whole process (worldmatrix might be set to identity insted of being destoried but I dont see any advantage in this). Bad thing about this is if you have forest full of trees and trees doesnt move nor the ground, every tree recalculate its world position anyway. This can be prevented by augumenting stage 1 and 2 and extending node with flag.

**EDIT 2**

Model matrix is representation how is model transformed (understand as translated, rotated and scaled) from 0,0,0 position (understand it as base point).

Scenegraph does only one thing, it changes each models basepoint from something static (= static position like 0,0,0) to something relative (another model position).

Each model still has its own model matrix, which represent its transformation from base point.

> but I think you cannot transform matrices over and over and back and again and in different ways without any set-back, can you?

This is exactly what you can and should do! Matrix 4x4 contain 16 numbers and has predefined operations. Position, rotation and scale are 3 vectors, each with 3 numbers, which is 9 numbers and these represent current state of the model (in 3D, in 2D we have different transformations). We componed them into one mat4, so mat4 contains the current state of the model and we dont need to maintain 3 vectors anymore, all is in the matrix.

[image: Matrix used to describe 3D transformation]

When you call `mat4.translate()`, `mat4.rotate()`, `mat4.scale()` you transfrom the model. `mat4.multiply(mat4)` applies not just one but set of transformations.

In addition, matrix was designed [to not have its operations commutative!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) 
matA * matB != matB * matA. Which is very helpful for example, if you first rotate the camera and then translate it, it will move in direction it is looking. Sometimes you doesnt want it, but most of the time you want it.

In case you doesn't want it, you set matrix back to identity, which is reset the model to default position and then do transformation in way you want.

For example for car with velocity, with each `tick()` you do just small delta translation on matrix and it will move in direction it is heading. And if player is turning right, you just do small delta rotation to the right and then translation. And you have nice smooth and easy car movement with just few lines of code.

In scene graph there is also world position for each model, which is sum of all previous parent matrices and model matrix to one. It prevents to do all the multiplications for each model separately so very deep simbling models doenst require a lot of multiplications. This is important, imagine you need to do all the multiplications 60 times per sec and all this with CPU.

This is not from my mind, all the stuff about matrices is native in GLSL already. Graphic cards are prepared to work with matrices.

> I mean, you will already have recognized that I'm not that much into matrix-math

You dont have to, you just need to use 4 functions: translate, rotate, scale and mutliply and to know that model state is represent by one matrix and this is all. Everything behind is ment to be in the blackbox. You dont have to know how to get model distance from the matrix, you just need to know: once you do modelviewprojectionmatrix * vertex, model will be rendered.

Comment: Hello Entity Black! Without knowing the _abstract-node_-concept, that is what I used to do until now: I didn't mention it in the question, but in my _node_-object, I also have an option for an additional _parentNode_, which is only a matrix and holds no information about drawing stuff. But I want my code to be more variable, so that it's possible to establish parent-child-relationships of arbitrary depth. The solution presented on **www.webglfundamentals.org** seems to be exactly what I want (I mean, to tell a node, _not_ to draw something and just calc matrices isn't that big of a deal)...

Comment: ...I also understand the concept of how it's done, but I struggle to do the last step and adjust the code from the tutorial to my existing functions: It's no problem to establish the parent-child-relationships (it's pretty similar to DOM, isn't it), but I ask myself _when_ and _where_ to update the matrices. I mean, in my former model it was easy, because the nodes matrix-calcs didn't affect other nodes matrices (only local- and _local_-parent-matrix), so, at drawing-time, I could just loop through my `nodeList` and tell each node to calc their matrix(or matrices) and then draw itself...

Comment: ...but by doing this, at each drawing-call, the local- and the _local_-parent-matrix are set back to _identity_. So, when on one hand, the function to update the _world-matrices_ is traversing recursively through all children of a node - and on the other hand, the nodes matrices are set back to _identity_ with every drawing-call before being transformed, the previous calculations would be null and void. Therefore the question of when and where to call the `updateWorldMatrix`-function(s) and when to set the matrices back to _identity_.

Comment: Thank you very much! You brought some light into this! The reason I set matrices back to _identity_ is because that's the way I learned to animate things: I mean, you will already have recognized that I'm not that much into matrix-math, but I think you cannot transform matrices over and over and back and again and in different ways without any set-back, can you? So, while setting the matrices back to identity, I keep the range of my transformations within each `tick( )`, so that I only have to care about the _actual state_ of transformation. But maybe I misunderstood the concept behind... ;-)

Comment: Well, I remember when starting with WebGL, I used to have one _modelMatrix_ for all objects to draw (instead of local matrices), which of cause had to be set back to _identity_ before using it for another object - I think I just never thought about it and simply went on doing it that way. Beside that, I think it could be a good idea, to make the `rootNode` something like the `body`-element in HTML, and append each regular node to it as default; the _viewMatrix_ / _cameraMatrix_ would then be just the rootNodes position. Mhh.. let's see! - Anyway, your answers are very helpful! - Thanks again!